# Forgot Windows 10 IOT Password For Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: powershell, windows-10-iot-core

I successfully installed Windows 10 on my local machine and the raspberry pi 2. Following the directions verbatim (http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PowerShell.htm) I got to the part where I successfully log into the raspberry pi 2 via the default password [p@ssw0rd] and then change the password via the command "net user Administrator [new password]".

However, I made a syntactical error (I thought the "[]" where required). As a result I received an Access Denied message because I had basically forgotten my password. Thankfully I was able to catch the error that I made and have since then logged in successfully.

My question is, if I never did figure out my password, how would I go about resetting it for the Raspberry Pi 2? Would I have to format the SD card and start over, or is there a better way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it is not directly programming related but that of OS troubleshooting. Could be better for SuperUser or the RaspberryPi SE?

Comment: I'm fine with you guys closing this question, it started out as a powershell question but when I was able to figure out what was wrong I figured I'd continue to ask what was the best way to reset the password (since I couldn't find that answer on the exchange sites). I'm new to stack exchange so I'm not sure how to do that on my end (if it's possible).

Comment: Hi @EvanPederson Whilst this is not technically programming, it is an issue that all raspberry pi programmers face on a monthly or sometimes weekly basis, especially if you are working with many devices that may have been provisioned by other team members. try posting in http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ otherwise many questions will get flagged as off topic.

Comment: I found that somehow my keyboard language had changed to US English (from British English) causing the "@" in "p@ssw0rd" to show as a quotation mark ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the easiest way to reimage.  One thing to keep handy is the image you are loading on your Pi on your laptop so you can just reload it quickly.  Create the image after you set up everything on the Pi, or several images for each step to save yourself downloading/recompiling several packages.